# how to search query in elastic search with synonyms in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, synonym

I am not able to understand the implementation of the elastic search query along with the synonym table. With a general query, I don't have any search problems but incorporating synonyms as become an issue to me.

```
es.search(index='data_inex', body={
        "query": {
            "match": {"inex": "tren"}
        },
        "settings": {
            "filter": {
                "synonym": {
                  "type": "synonym",
                  "lenient": true,
                  "synonyms": [ "foo, baz", "tren, hut" ]
              }
            
            }
        
        }
    }
)
```

Also, is it possible to use a file instead of this array?

Answer (score 0):

**Check the documentation:** [Click Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html#analysis-synonym-tokenfilter)

You can configure synonyms file as well:

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [ "synonym" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt" // <======== location of synonym file
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Please note:**

1. Changes in the synonyms file will not reflect in the documents indexed before the change. Re-indexing is required for the same.
2. You cannot change the mapping (including the analyzer) of an existing field. What you need to do if you want to change the mapping of existing documents is reindex those documents to another index with the updated mapping.
3. Search query doesn't support "settings".

Comment: I am not doing a put request in ES, but only get request, not sure how to use above code snippet with my code.

Comment: Do you know the elastic equivalent of your python query ? ES doesn't support setting in _search query.

Comment: yes .. there are 2 ways ... a) index time analysis (synonym analyser to be added in the field during mapping) b) Query time analysis (In this case synonym analyser needs to be defined during query time)

Comment: Did my answer help? You able to rectify the issue?

Comment: i appreciate you concern towards my problem really. But code you provided is something i have already seen in es official docs. I would appreciate if you can provide me the python code for search query with semantics which was my question because my code above is not giving me any answers. I am not getting any leads on   this.

Comment: ohh ... Python is not something which i know .. Hence it would be difficult for me to come up with python syntax.